# Using C/C++ Modules in Meteor Tutorial

Tags: meteor

Does anyone have a tutorial how to use a C++ module from NPM in Meteor? Running the normal: meteor npm install and importing with the package returns this message.

```
Error: module.useNode() must succeed for native .node modules
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an unusual server configuration. Some common problems that break compilation are:

- Incorrect permissions for various directories. This may mean you've been running as root for some meteor installation commands, which then prevents the local user's access to those directories for compilation.
- A missing or broken compiler toolchain.
- A bad package or one that is untested for your hosting platform.

I'd discourage you from trying to run locally on an desktop Linux installation if you're unfamiliar with some of these gotchas. Use a virtual machine for development. I'd recommend Vagrant using IntelliJ's WebStorm for native integration.

Meteor is generally deployed on Linux using the Amazon AMI or Ubuntu on AWS, Galaxy or Modulus.

If you think everything's in order and you're having issues with Galaxy or Modulus, reach out to their support.

Comment: This is locally on a Macbook.

Comment: I'd recommend using a virtual machine to use a C++ module on a Mac. C++ modules in NPM are not supported in Meteor's node on Mac configuration. I'd suggest using vagrant.